# How to showcase a conlang?

Tags: conlang-documentation

How would one go about "Showcasing" a conlang, other than by works of fiction, like Tolkien? I want to have a way to share my language to the world in full, with outlined grammar and everything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The traditional method of promoting a conlang was creating a booklet, often self-published and self-promoted by the conlang creator.

Nowadays, it is easier to set up a comprehensive website essentially containing the content of that booklet.

The content of the booklet or website typically consists of

- A teaching grammar of the conlang
- A vocabulary list
- Sample sentences like you find in Teach Yourself a language books
- Sample texts, often translations of well known texts into the conlang

Frequently used sample texts include [The Lord's prayer](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/207/why-is-the-lords-prayer-so-common-as-a-translation), the Tower-of-Babel fable, "The North Wind and the Sun", and the Declaration of Human Rights.